# How do I clone/pull from GitHub, but push to Kiln?

Tags: git, mercurial, github, kiln, hg-git

I don't necessarily have a preference for either Git or Mercurial. I have both of them installed and find them equally difficult to get my head around. I mainly use Mercurial because our repositories live in Kiln.

I just cloned a project from GitHub using Hg and Hg-Git. I want to pull and merge changes from GitHub to my local repository, but I want to push changes from my local hg repository to Kiln.

Can this be done or is the connection to GitHub lost once it's converted to Hg?

Comment: What is your question?  Have you tried to `hg push http://path/to/kiln`?  If that is all you want to do, then you can set `default-push` in your `.hg\hgrc` file to automatically push to Kiln as well.  See `hg help config` for details on `default-push`.

Comment: Thanks. I clarified my question to the best of my abilities.  You almost answered my question, but will I be able to pull changes from Github or is the link lost?

Comment: I've just written a script to keep some GitHub and Kiln repos in sync. I can't answer here, but you can see the script in another answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15370481/25124

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you clone a project in Mercurial, the path that you cloned from is set as the `default`.  Both push and pull will use this path if none other is specified on the command-line.

If you want your push and pull URLs to be different, put the following inside your `<repo>\.hg\hgrc`:

```
[paths]
default = http://path/to/pull/repo
default-push = http://path/to/push/repo
```

With these set

- `hg pull` will automatically pull from `default`
- `hg push` will automatically push to `default-push`

See [`hg help urls`](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/urls) for details.